# How to get id of element on the click [JS]

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to connect the button with the id of the div, now they're connected only to classes.

```
function addClass(e) {
  // to get the correct effect
  effect = e.target.getAttribute('data-effect');
  // adding the effects
  menu.classList.toggle(effect);
  menu.classList.toggle('st-menu-open');

  // console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-effect'));
}
```

Full code:
https://jsfiddle.net/eb26904s/

What I want to achieve:

- Menu1 - open the div with id="menu1"
- Menu2 - open the div with id="menu2"
- Click anywhere - closes the menu

Now both of them opens the menu with "cv" class.

Comment: e.target.id i believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click `.click`, both `ui` and `cv` show, but you only see `cv` because it's above `ui`. I suggest hiding both when start and show one when menu clicked.

This is the demo based on your code:

```js
var click = document.querySelectorAll('.click');
var st_menu = document.querySelectorAll('.st-menu');
var menu = document.querySelector('#st-container');
var effect;

for (var i = 0; i < click.length; i++) {
  click[i].addEventListener('click', addClass)
}


function addClass(e) {
  // to get the correct effect
  effect = e.target.getAttribute('data-effect');
  for (var i = 0; i < st_menu.length; i++) {
    st_menu[i].classList.remove("d-block");
  }
  var target_id = e.target.getAttribute('data-target');
  var target = document.getElementById(target_id);
  target.classList.toggle("d-block");
  // adding the effects
  menu.classList.toggle(effect);
  menu.classList.toggle('st-menu-open');
}
```

```css
.ui {
  display: none;
  background: #215DD1;
  color: #fff;
}

.cv {
  display: none;
  background: #FF9F2F;
  color: #fff;
}

.cv.d-block, .ui.d-block {
  display: block;
}

.st-container {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.st-menu {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 100;
 visibility: hidden;
 width: 300px;
 height: 100%;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 transition: all 0.5s;
}

.st-effect-1.st-menu {
 visibility: visible;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
 transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

.st-effect-1.st-menu-open .st-effect-1.st-menu {
 visibility: visible;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.st-effect-1.st-menu::after {
 display: none;
}

body {
 background: #444;
 color: #48a770;
}
```

```html
<div id="st-container">

  <div class="ui st-menu st-effect-1" id="menu1">
  </div>
  
  <div class="cv st-menu st-effect-1" id="menu2">
  </div>
  
  <div class="click" style="position: relative; left: 50%;" data-effect="st-effect-1" data-target="menu1">Menu1</div> 
  
   <div class="click" style="position: relative; left: 50%;" data-effect="st-effect-1" data-target="menu2">Menu2</div> 
  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

more simple with event delegation..

```js
const StContainer = document.querySelector('#st-container')

StContainer.onclick = e=>
  {
  if (e.target.className!='click') return

  console.log(e.target.textContent, e.target.dataset.effect)

  let STmenu = document.getElementById(e.target.textContent.toLowerCase())

  STmenu.classList.toggle(e.target.dataset.effect)
  STmenu.classList.toggle('st-menu-open');
  }
```

```css
.ui {
  background: #215DD1;
  color: #fff;
}

.cv {
  background: #FF9F2F;
  color: #fff;
}

.st-container {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.st-menu {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 100;
 visibility: hidden;
 width: 300px;
 height: 100%;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 transition: all 0.5s;
}

.st-effect-1.st-menu {
 visibility: visible;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
 transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

.st-effect-1.st-menu-open .st-effect-1.st-menu {
 visibility: visible;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.st-effect-1.st-menu::after {
 display: none;
}

body {
 background: #444;
 color: #48a770;
}
```

```html
<div id="st-container">
  <div class="ui st-menu st-effect-1" id="menu1">
  </div>
  <div class="cv st-menu st-effect-1" id="menu2">
  </div>
  <div class="click" style="position: relative; left: 50%;" data-effect="st-effect-1">Menu1</div> 
  <div class="click" style="position: relative; left: 50%;" data-effect="st-effect-1">Menu2</div> 
</div>
```